# Validation JQuery : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I always get error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

when I type correct email in my form. Custom massages doesn't work too.
Function `?module=auth&amp;action=registration` work properly (it returns string 'false' or 'true').

I use this plugin: [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) .

I think problem is in these files below.

**custom.validation.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#reg").validate({

       rules: {
               'u1[firstName]': "required",
               'u2[firstName]': "required",
               'u1[lastName]' : "required",
               'u2[lastName]' : "required",
               'u1[email]' : {
                   "required" : true,
                   "email" : true,
                   "remote" : { 

                    url: '?module=auth&action=checkemail',
                    type: "post",
                    data:
                      {
                          'u1[email]': function()
                          {
console.log($("#email1").val());
                              return $("#email1").val();
                          }
                    }                  
               },
               'u2[email]' : "required" 
       },      
       messages: {
               'u1[firstName]': {
                       required: "My requied text"
               }
       }    
    }
});
});
```

and **form**:

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="imie" >Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="u1[firstName]"{if $smarty.post.u1.firstName} value="{$smarty.post.u1.firstName}"{/if}>
    <label for="nazwisko" >Lastname:</label>
    <input type="text" name="u1[lastName]" {if $smarty.post.u1.lastName} value="{$smarty.post.u1.lastName}"{/if}>
    <label for="adresEmail">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="text" name="u1[email]" id="email1" {if $smarty.post.u1.email} value="{$smarty.post.u1.email}"{/if}>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the full URL and not just the query string?

Comment: Your posted HTML does not match your jQuery.  Where are the `u2` fields?  Also, would be better to post the _rendered_ HTML as that's the only thing the client-side code it going to see/use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`messages` is a stand-alone option, but you've accidentally placed it *inside* of `rules`, which breaks the plugin.

It appears to work without errors when this syntax is fixed.  (BTW, the code is easier to troubleshoot when it's properly indented and tabbed.)

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/sERPT/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#reg").validate({

        rules: {
            'u1[firstName]': "required",
            'u2[firstName]': "required",
            'u1[lastName]': "required",
            'u2[lastName]': "required",
            'u2[email]': "required",
            'u1[email]': {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: '?module=auth&action=checkemail',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        'u1[email]': function () {
                            console.log($("#email1").val());
                            return $("#email1").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages: {
            'u1[firstName]': {
                required: "My requied text"
            }
        }
    });

});
```